# Extension for voice captcha

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

Which is the best extension for voice captcha in joomla.

I have used recaptcha that is the default in joomla but the voice is not clear in it.

Comment: You know, if the voice is can be heard more clearly, one can crack the captcha using speech recognition? A certain degree of background-noise is needed.

Comment: I agrees with your point but in recaptcha it is not even least clear and how can we find the text in voice.

Comment: I think there is some sort of bug in the recaptcha voice. It's sounds like a mumbling alien. Unfortunately I don't think there is anything else specifically for Joomla. It might be best looking into other validation systems and trying to integrate one of them.